# Creating A List of Methods To Be Called

Tags: java

Is there a way to make a list of "Instructions" to call?

```
List<???> methods = new ArrayList<???>();
for (int i = 0; i < methods.size(); i++) {
    ((???)methods.get(i)).do();
}
```

That's basically what I have a problem with
I want to put

```
methods.add(graphics.setColor(Color.WHITE));
methods.add(graphics.drawRect(0, 0, 32, 32));
```

Then have those methods be called in the loop?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could create an interface for a generic function:

```
interface GenericFunction
{
    void do();
}
```

Then for each function you want to use with it, create a class:

```
class SetColor implements GenericFunction
{
    private Color m_Color;

    SetColor(Color c) { m_Color = c; }

    void do()
    {
        graphics.setColor(m_Color);
    }
}
```

Then create instances of those function classes and put them in the array list:

```
List<GenericFunction> methods= new List<GenericFunction>();
methods.add(new SetColor(Color.WHITE));
for (int i = 0; i < methods.size(); i++) {
    methods.get(i).do();
}
```

Comment: For what I'm doing, this is a better solution :D

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
List<Runnable> methods = new ArrayList<>();

methods.add(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public final void run() {
        graphics.setColor(Color.WHITE));
    }
});
methods.add(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public final void run() {
        graphics.drawRect(0, 0, 32, 32));
    }
});

for(Runnable method : methods)
    method.run();
```